# LM741CN Wired as Voltage Follower Will not Output less than 2V

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have designed a circuit to measure 0-12.2V and Scale it to 0-10V from a PLC input to read. I have put an LM741CN in the circuit as a voltage follow to isolate the test circuit from the measurement circuit.

All is well except that when I input less than 2V into the op amp it stops following the voltage and continues to output about 2V I have input 0V into it and I still get about 2 volts out.

I can't find anything on the spec sheet about there being a minimum voltage output. What am I doing wrong?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWDZd2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: My guess is that you will receive a lot of answers telling you about the output swing limits. Have you grabbed up a datasheet PDF and done a search for that term, "swing," to see what it says?

Comment: Have you read the LM741 datasheet - particularly the "Output Voltage Swing" line under "Electrical Characteristics"?

Comment: @TheColonel26: I edited your schematic and used GND symbols to eliminate some of the criss-cross wiring. The answer you are looking for is max and min output vs supply voltage. Check the datasheet.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp

Comment: "*I have put an LM741CN in the circuit as a voltage follow to isolate the test circuit from the measurement circuit.*" You are not *isolating* it but rather buffering it. Is there any reason you can't use a 1.22:1 potential divider?

Comment: It isn't just the output range.  The input range is limited as well.  The 741 is just plain and simple outdated.

Comment: **Stop using the LM741. It's obsolete.** If you want a general-purpose op-amp, use a more modern part. (LM358 and TLC274 are two cheap options.)

Comment: @Transistor: this circuit is actually to measure voltage drop, through another device. Supply voltsge for thst device is 12V, When the device is open, I need it to read 12V, however with just the divider it will pull down the Voltage to 11.88ish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 741 is not a rail to rail amplifier.

The thing on the spec sheet you want is the  *minimum output voltage* specification, which depending on things like rail voltage and load will always be a few volts *above* the negative supply rail.

In your case, the negative rail is at 0v, so the minimum output voltage you can expect is 2(ish) volts if it doesn't have to sink a current, and 3(ish) if it does.

Use a 'single supply amplifier' like the LM324 if you want your inputs and outputs to include ground, or a 'rail to rail' (R2R) amplifier if you want to swing all the way to both rails.

In all cases, 741 is never the right amplifier to use these days.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that have been asked dozens of times before.